# How to prove matrix obeying certain relation is invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $n$ be a positive integer, $M$ be an $n\times n$ matrix with complex entries, which may or may not be diagonalizable, and assume that for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}-\mathbb{R}$, we have that $$ -\frac{\Im\left(M\right)}{\Im\left(\lambda\right)}$$ is a positive definite matrix, where $$ \Im\left(M\right) \equiv\frac{1}{2i}\left(M-M^{\ast}\right) $$ and $$ \Im\left(\lambda\right)\equiv \frac{1}{2i}\left(\lambda-\bar{\lambda}\right)$$

**Question**: How to prove that $\lambda$ is not an eigenvalue of $M$?

The case that $n=1$ is clear, and I think so is the case that $M$ is diagonalizable, but otherwise I am a bit stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mu$ be an eigenvalue of $M$, and $x$ a corresponding eigenvector with unit magnitude. Then $Mx = \mu x$ and $x^*M^* = (Mx)^* = \bar \mu x^*$, so that
\begin{align*}
x^* \Im(M) x &= \dfrac{1}{2i}(x^*\mu x - \bar \mu x^*x)\\
& = \dfrac{1}{2i}(\mu - \bar \mu)\\
& = \Im(\mu)
\end{align*}
(since $x^*x = 1$).

This implies that
$$x^* \left( - \dfrac{\Im(M)}{\Im(\lambda)} \right) x = - \dfrac {\Im(\mu)} {\Im(\lambda)}.$$
If $\mu = \lambda$, this would have value $-1$, which is not possible since $- \dfrac{\Im(M)}{\Im(\lambda)}$ is positive definite. Therefore, $\lambda$ cannot be an eigenvalue of $M$.